# Hide a folder of ebooks on Kindle

Tags: ebook-readers, kindle-paperwhite

So I have this folder in the documets folder of my Kindle Paperwhite which contains books that are inappropriate ebooks for small children(my cousins).
I don't want to delete them and kids mode won't do.

I wanted to know if there is way I can hide all the ebooks stored in that folder from showing in my collection.

**Note:** These books are not on cloud I have transferred them from my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a bit of an involved solution, but you could access the "documents" folder on your kindle via miniUSB/USB data and charging cable with your computer, and compress the book (and remove the original). Kindle will not recognize the file anymore, though it still contains the same data.

NOTE, however, that if the file in question has a duplicate in the cloud, the duplicate will remain accessible.

For this purpose, I recommend Settings>Device Options>Parental Controls>Restrictions>Cloud (and an adequate password).

You may also want to restrict access to the Kindle Store? Just sayin'.

These steps will secure the files on your kindle, but inaccessible by kindle;
in your kindle cloud, but restricted to those with the password.

(Just tested on my Kindle 7th Gen.)

Comment: isn't there a way that does not involve me plugging my device to computer

Answer (score 1):

If you use KoboReader on a hacked Kindle, you have an option to show/hide hidden folders (standard . dot_folders). 
It doesn't make it impossible for another user to see them, but harder to find.